# How to use replace for an array of regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace

So I want to take in a string, and test for a series of possible words that might be contained in that string, and if any of those words do occur in the string, i want to replace those with a specific word, in this case "is".

```
function replace_is (string) {
    var exps = [/looks/, /appears/, /seems/, /feels/];
    for(i = 0;i<exps.length;i++) {
        if (string.search(exps[i])==-1) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            string.replace(exps[i], "is")
            return string;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Problem is, this does not work. What is a better way to do this? Or why might this not be working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe string.replace modifies string, so, you should just:

```
return string.replace(exps[i], "is");
```